# Relay: how to get connection from store when used with order_by or other params?

Tags: reactjs, relayjs, relay, relaymodern

I have a question regarding ConnectionHandler used in updater. I am reading the example and found

```
import {ConnectionHandler} from 'relay-runtime';

// The `friends` connection record can be accessed with:
const user = store.get(userID);
const friends = RelayConnectionHandler.getConnection(
 user,                        // parent record
 'FriendsFragment_friends'    // connection key
 {orderby: 'firstname'}       // 'filters' that is used to identify the connection
);
// Access fields on the connection:
const edges = friends.getLinkedRecords('edges');
```

So the connections could accept {orderby: 'firstname'}. What is my orderby field can take in either firstname or secondname or fullname? So if I am sorting by firstname, I should update the connection with orderby = firstname and when I am sorting by lastname, I should get connection by orderby = lastname ...
How do I know which orderby I am under or could I just update the "current one"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Junchao, I see that you took this example from the relay docs right? This `orderby` that is passed, you are not actually telling Relay to order the edges for you by `firstname`, but this parameter is the `filters` one, which is used to identify the connection like said on the comment.
If you specified a `filter` on your query, you also must pass the filter on `getConnection`, otherwise, you won't find it.

:)

Comment: I actually solved this myself. Relay has a getConnections in plan but not out yet